# SET command with multiple embedded variables

Tags: mysql, set

I would like to be able to use the SET command which in itself is referring to TWO other previously "set" values. As follows:

```
SET @sample_table = ' sample5 ';
SET @condition = 1;

SET @newvalue = (SELECT col_name from @sample_table where condition=@condition);

SELECT @newvalue;
```

If I only refer to ONE previously @set item then the query works, but if I add another one, it will not work anymore.

How to overcome this problem?
(the col_name is referring to an existing column in the "sample5" table)

Later on, there will be a large amount of separate new queries which all of them require this @newvalue in their select statements respectively...

Comment: You can use 1 `SET`  with comma-seperated variables. Tho this doesn't seem very elegant nor useful to me.. why not use a transaction within a shell script or something.

Comment: Thanks, Dan, I need to use this format since I have lots of queries following this setup that would require the @newvalue to be fed into them automatically. Could you provide an example though of what you suggest?

Comment: @fancyPants - you were spot on and I was able to extract my answer from the reference you provided.

Comment: @Stan Feel free to upvote my answer :)